# Jackson Deserialize Object containing array of objects

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, mapping

I am trying to deserialize JSON response into an object like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Group {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<EffectiveRoles> roles;
}
```

where *EffectiveRoles* is basically:

```
@Data
public class EffectiveRole {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String self;
}
```

The JSON response I get upon GET requests looks like this:

```
{
  "roles": {
    "references": [
      {
        "role": {
          "id": "",
          "name": "",
          "self": ""
        },
        "self": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I deserialize this response to create *roles* array containing mentioned values?
I am having trouble implementing proper ObjectMapping using Jackson.
The easiest thing would be to make object structure look like incoming JSON but I would like to make it more accessible for further fronted usage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming flexjson is present on classpath so imports will be :

```
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;
import flexjson.transformer.DateTransformer;
```

and code to convert will be :

```
new JSONDeserializer<List<Group>>().use(null, ArrayList.class).use("values", Group.class).deserialize(json);
```

//here `json` is the String which contains json response

Add below dependency in pom.xml to get flexjson.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
   <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```